# Create multiple variables from existing variables variables using a statistical method simultaneously in R

Tags: r, variables

Using bloms' formula, I created a new variable from an existing one whilst keeping them both in the DF thusly:

```
DF$R_BLR<-blom(DF$R, method = "blom")
```

I have 7 other variables (S,T,U,V,W,X,Y, to create new ones (S_BLR T_BLR etc) whilst keeping the originals) I want to perform the same operation on and was wondering if there is a way I could do it in one go rather than type them all out as per the first one.

The existing vars are all next to each other in the DF (columns 1-7). I have tried using the mutate function, as this worked previously when I wanted to recode categories in other variables, but this is just a straight transformation and I can't quite figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::across`, here is an example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rcompanion)

# from `?blom`'s examples
Value = c(709,679,699,657,594,677,592,538,476,508,505,539)
Sex   = c(rep("Male",3), rep("Female",3), rep("Male",3), rep("Female",3))
Fat   = c(rep("Fresh", 6), rep("Rancid", 6))

Sokal = data.frame(Value, Sex, Fat)

# dplyr::across with the example above (one varialbe)

Sokal %>% 
  mutate(across(Value, list(BLR = ~ blom(.x, method = "blom"))))
#>    Value    Sex    Fat  Value_BLR
#> 1    709   Male  Fresh  1.6350393
#> 2    679   Male  Fresh  0.7916386
#> 3    699   Male  Fresh  1.1139372
#> 4    657 Female  Fresh  0.3119191
#> 5    594 Female  Fresh  0.1024905
#> 6    677 Female  Fresh  0.5361763
#> 7    592   Male Rancid -0.1024905
#> 8    538   Male Rancid -0.5361763
#> 9    476   Male Rancid -1.6350393
#> 10   508 Female Rancid -0.7916386
#> 11   505 Female Rancid -1.1139372
#> 12   539 Female Rancid -0.3119191

# applying this example to your data.frame
your_df <- setNames(as.list(1:8), LETTERS[18:25]) %>% as_tibble

# using tidyselect `matches()` with a regex in `across`
your_df %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("[R-Y]"),
                list(BLR = ~ blom(.x, method = "blom"))))

# or select variables by position in `across`
your_df %>% 
  mutate(across(1:7,
                list(BLR = ~ blom(.x, method = "blom"))))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

your_df <- setNames(as.list(1:8), LETTERS[18:25]) %>% as_tibble

So does this convert the first 8 rows in the DF to a tibble? What does LETTERS[18:25]) do?

Comment: This line is just there to create a `data.frame` that has similar names as your data, since your post doesn’t contain any sample data (which would have made it easier to replicate the problem). You should ignore this line and just replace `your_df` with your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply` -

```
new_cols <- paste0(names(df)[1:7], '_BLR')
df[new_cols] <- lapply(df[1:7], blom, method = "blom")
```